# Pygame cannot open sound file

Tags: python, audio, pygame

```
import pygame, time
from pygame.locals import *

soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('beeps.wav')
soundObj.play()

time.sleep(1) # wait and let the sound play for 1 second
soundObj.stop()
```

and it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jauhar/Desktop/Python/sounds.py", line 4, in <module>
    soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('beeps.wav')
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'beeps.wav'
```

The beeps.wav file is saved in the same directory as the python file the code is in.

I can't understand why it won't work!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use pygames' library's unless you initialize either the modules your using or all of pygame.

```
    pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096) #frequency, size, channels, buffersize
    pygame.init() #turn all of pygame on.
```

do these before you do anything in pygame. I recommend it.

Comment: It may be a format or feature in the format it doesn't support. Pygames flexibility is rather limited and finding what works can be really constraining. I only use pygame now for events and an OpenGL window. If I ever do sound again I will probably use OpenAL.

Comment: It turned out that the frequency rate was too high for pygame, so I used one of the free tools to reduce the sampling rate (to smth like 128 bps) and it worked.

Comment: @Kaliber64 What's a 'too high frequency for pygame' exactly? Is the limitation really due to pygame or the computer CPU??

Comment: 44100 is standard output quality. All Input from files will be constrained to this output. As long as the Pygame muxer(I think thats the right term) can handle the file you give it the sound will work. Unfortunately I have no idea on its limitations. Now all hardware less than 10 years old should not constrain what pygames sound library is capable of so don't worry about the computers CPU.

Comment: What frequency should be set in pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096) if the audio file is at 16000Hz?

Answer (score 12):

Pygame (version 2.9 at least) doesn't support 32-bit float WAVs.
Re-encode it to a signed 16-bit WAV (using Audacity for example).

Comment: wav is more supported than ogg, try wav in the future if your OGG fails

Answer (score 0):

Try logging this information, and you may find your problem.

```
import os
os.getcwd() # Log this line.
soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('beeps.wav')
```

This should tell you what directory your application is looking in when trying to access your sound file. You'll probably find it's at the base of your game directory.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help.

I modified the code to this:

`import pygame, time, os
from pygame.locals import *

print(os.getcwd()) # Log this line
soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('beeps.wav')
soundObj.play()

time.sleep(1) # wait and let the sound play for 1 second
soundObj.stop()`

You're right in that it's looking at the location at the base of my game directory.  I'm not sure still how to fix my problem though as everything still seems to be working as intended.

Comment: You need to init pygame. See kaliber's answer. If you need to use a subdir, use `filename = os.path.join("sounds", "beeps.wav")`

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar problem, I found that the size of the .wav file had a bearing on the problem. Making the .wav file smaller enabled it to work without making major modifications to the problem

Answer (score 0):

The same program works for me if I create a display surface before playing the sound.

```
    #! Python 3
'''
Making games with python chapter 2 program 5
'''
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import*

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption("Sound!!")

soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('badswap.wav')
soundObj.play()
time.sleep(1) #wait and let the sound play for X second
soundObj.stop()

while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I confirmed. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Have the sound file after pygame.init(). I had this problem but after placing the sound file after that it worked just fine for me.

Comment: Some sample code to go along with your statement would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same problem, and removing the ID tag from the wav file worked. So could be worth checking if the file has one!