# Pygame error: not able to open .wav file

Tags: python, pygame

I have a problem with my Pygame program. I need help. 
The wav file is in the same directory as the python file.
I run It in terminal- Python3:

```
import pygame.mixer
sounds = pygame.mixer
sounds.init()

def wait_finish(channel):
    while channel.get_busy():
        pass

asked = 0
true = 0
false = 0

choice = str(input("Push 1 for true, 2 for false, 0 to end"))
while choice != '0':
      if choice == '1':
             asked = asked + 1
             true = true + 1
             s = sounds.Sound("correct.wav")
             wait_finish(s.play())
      if choice == '2':
             asked = asked + 1
             false = false + 1
             s = sounds.Sound("wrong.wav")
             wait_finish(s.play())
      choice = str(input("Push 1 for true, 2 for false, 0 to end"))

print ("you asked" +str(asked) + "questions")
print ("there were" +str(false) + "wrong answers")
print ("and" + str(true) + "correct answers")
```

It throws- pygame.error:

> Unable to open file 'correct.wav'

Comment: Cut and paste the exact error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pygame cannot open sound file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845896/pygame-cannot-open-sound-file)

Comment: You have `             s = sounds.Sound("correct.wav")` and `s = sounds.Sounds("wrong.wav")` , which is correct Sound or Sounds

Comment: @user696 please confirm the suggestion of Alex.S  Did you try that?

Comment: I saw the solution of Alex.S before I put description of my problem here. And yes, thanks to Rolf of Saxony I amended there was a mistake with sounds.sound() but still not working. I have read the other advices on net. I'm using Linux Xubuntu and python3.

Comment: `def wait_finish(channnel):` has 3 n's and you still have not posted the exact error that you get on the command line

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it is the last row below the code. I've cut&paste from terminal:      Push 1 for true, 2 for false, 0 to end2
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "python_docs./hfprog_sounds/pygame_quiz.py", line 25, in     <module>
        s = sounds.Sound("wrong.wav")
    pygame.error: Unable to open file 'wrong.wav'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, could not get this code to work:

```
correctSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('jingle3.wav')
```

I got pygame error:

> Unable to open file 'jingle3.wav'

The problem was solved by loading the 'jingle3.wav' into Audicity and changing it from 32-bit PCM to a 16-bit PCM .wav-file. After that the pygame.mixer.Sound worked perfectly.

I got this tip on this forum, and it worked!

Comment: What forum, specifically, and do you have a link to the original?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have a discussion in the comments section I'll post this.
Once `def wait_finish(channnel):` has been altered to `def wait_finish(channel):` and the issue with `sounds.Sound` rather than `sounds.Sounds` has been resolved, the program works fine with normal .wav files on my machine.
I am convinced that the error of Sound or Sounds for calling the wrong.wav file to be played would explain the "unable to open file wrong.wav" message.
If pygame doesn't like something about the file it may well not play it and this is where a line like:

```
sounds.pre_init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)
```

(called before `sounds.init()`) might come into play.
(NB you might have to use a different buffer option as I am testing with pygame for python 2.7)

On my box, if pygame doesn't like or cannot find the file, I get no error at all but the speakers click when the call to play is made.
All I can suggest at this point is that you try an entirely different wav file to the current one you are using for wrong answers and see if it makes a difference.
Just for the record, I changed your wait_finish function to :

```
def wait_finish(channel):
    while channel.get_busy():
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Comment: A few days ago I reinstalled Linux, instead of installing Ubuntu I installed Xubuntu which is the best for older computers as I have and now there is no problem, my program works perfectly, I can hear the sounds, no problem with .wav files. I'd like to thank for your time, especially to Rolf of Saxony, and advices and your patience, I'm very beginner in PC programming.